# circuit breaker problem after removing ceiling fan

Tags: electrical, wiring

I removed a Hunter Ceiling Fan.  I went to my circuit box and turned off the power from the circuit breaker it was on.  I capped the wires and then went to my circuit box to reset my circuit breaker.  Problem is that the circuit breaker will not click on.  It keeps clicking off.  What did I do wrong?  There are 3 wires and a copper wire.  One is white, one black and on green.  I capped them all separately.  Please help. A good portion of lights are out from the rest of the house because they are connected to this breaker.

Comment: Is that the *only* thing you removed?  What about the lightswitch?  If it was the only thing, and you really didn't splice two wires together, the only thing I can think of that would cause this would be that the nuts came loose from the wires which are now touching.

Comment: There was no lightswitch just a pull string.  I have capped the wires separately. should I cap them together. One is whit and one is black.

Comment: Sounds like you may have accidentally created a short.  Maybe a wire was nicked or rubbed against a metal box edge, etc. double check. Do not, I repeat DO NOT cap them together.  If no short is obvious, call in a pro.

Comment: Just to be sure, you cycled the breaker from TRIPPED to OFF and then back to ON?

Comment: Assuming you used wire nuts, you may have put one on that was too large. Which would likely fall off.